# How to correctly use Webpack async imports

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, lazy-loading

I'm trying to make a website with multiple components where each one is loaded with async import because I don't need every component (and maybe the user hasn't even access to it).

This is an example file structure (mine look somehow like that):

```
src/
  utils/
    ...
  index.ts
  components/
    home/
      ...
      index.ts
    about/
      ...
      index.ts
    contact/
      ...
      index.ts
```

Now I import the needed component somewhere in `src/index.ts` (I'm using TypeScript). Everything is fine until here.

Now the problem: When I need to use files from `utils` in a component which is loaded with lazy-loading, is that file bundeled twice? So the first time with the main chunk and the second time with the component chunk? How can I tell Webpack that this file is already included and doesn't have to be bundeled again? So I want to use the same cached version again in a component that is lazy-loaded.